# SQL SSRS Object has been disconnected or does not exist at the server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, query-optimization

I have a couple stored procedures that run for about 2-3 minutes a piece (lots of data). When I run the stored procedures inside SQL Server Management Studio, the queries run fine and return the appropriate data, however, when I run my SSRS Report, it errors out with "Object has been disconnected or does not exist at the server."

Any suggestions? I think it has to do with the time it takes to run all the queries.

I have tried setting WITH RECOMPILE with no luck.

Comment: Are the reports on the same server as the data?

Comment: No. They are on a different server. I thought of that, but when I use SQL Server Management Studio on the same server as the Report it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ed0ad78d-be17-475f-b8d1-9b2c642c1835

Looks like this may actually be a bug.

Comment: Just putting a link without any summary is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do a workaround for the report. Inside the stored procedure use a temporary table to store all the data and use filters against the temporary table.